# SeeTestAutomation: Is code export/record the correct way ? What are cons?

Tags: java, seetest

I am working on a new mobile application testing tool called SeeTest. We have done a feasibility study and decided to opt for SeeTest as tool of choice.

Now we are facing few challenges I would distribute them into different questions so that it is easier to focus.

Firstly, since SeeTest is a wonderful tool and famous for reducing lines of code to be written ( by using code export). I know it’s very comfortable, but I am equally fearful that it might cause issues once the automation test scripts starts piling on. So my question is recording and exporting the scripts a good option and what are the consequences of using it extensively in the project?

Addendum: Tool supports creating projects, recording and storing multiple scripts into it, but am planning to export the code in Java and to use Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to answer a SeeTest Automation tool related question, have been working with the tool for almost 2 years now.

I agree with you on SeeTest Automation being a wonderful tool , but I would say a No-No to just doing record and code export.

Well the good thing here is you have just started the project and I believe you haven’t put efforts on creating test scripts (now if you have put in lots of efforts, am sorry you might want to put some rework into it).

Now, if you have seen SeeTest scripts there are many lines of code which are repetitive like creating a ‘Client’ variable instance, setting device, setting android version, setting device speed and many more. Now each of your script needn’t do all these start-up tasks, may be you separate it out and place in a class file and use it wherever required.

Code exports usually contains lots of locators with xpath, you might want to reduce that wherever possible. Xpath are known to cause performance issues and creates flaky test scripts.

Abstraction is an important concept while creating your test scripts; I feel you should use Page Object Model Pattern, may be separate out all app functions into a different class say a Function Library class, this way of creating multiple layers of classes and spreading data across them will reduce maintenance work which will kick in once your project plans a new release.

So, to conclude I would suggest you to use code export wisely, there are scenarios where recording is useful like:

1. Locating few tricky elements.
2. Simulating complex user actions on Mobile Apps like Swipe, Pinch or few others.

Use code export but do a code refactoring (as mentioned above) once you put in the IDE.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great insight on the tool, I will perform a code refactoring once export is done. Thanks !